# how to get the current values of select input without using a form?

Tags: javascript

I have this code below I don't want to use a form on it.
the problem is it keeps logging the first option instead the one that I have selected?
any idea how to get the value that is getting selected ?

```js
function select() {
  let btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
  let numbers = document.querySelector('.numbers')
  let value = numbers.value
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(value);
  })
}

select()
```

```html
<div class="select">
          <select name="monthes" class="numbers">
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="36">36</option>
            <option value="48">48</option>
          </select>
          <button type="button" class="btn">Simulate</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: You set `let value = numbers.value` _once_ and then never again. Of course its value is only the initial one.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+input+value+always+empty) of [Why is the value of my input always empty if I store it in a variable?](/q/58078160/4642212).